# How does this specific nested for loop work in vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested-for-loop, code-visualization

I got a quiz question in my Full Stack Web Development online course that states the following:

```
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        sum = sum + i + j;
        continue;
    }
}
console.log(sum);
```

Now, the correct answer to the question is 25 according to the answer of the quiz, but I have no idea how it gets to 25? The closest I get when writing it out on paper to try and visualize it, is either 15 / 16.

Could someone please write a visualization that would make it clearer for me on how this nested loop gets to 25?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need `continue;`. Loops automatically continue unless you do something to stop it.

Comment: Yes, this was explained in the answer to the quiz that the "continue;" is basically useless and was placed there as a "test" due to it being a quiz. But I am trying to visualize how it gets to the number 25? I know I must be missing something simple, but do not know what I am not seeing/realizing.

Comment: How do you get to 15 or 16? Without knowing this, we don’t know where you went wrong. Please [edit] your question to provide details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a console after second for, you should see the visualization

```
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        console.log(`sum=${sum} i=${i} j=${j}`)
        sum = sum + i + j;
        continue;
    }
}
console.log(sum);

//output
// sum=0 i=0 j=0
// sum=0 i=0 j=1 
// sum=1 i=1 j=0 
// sum=2 i=1 j=1 
// sum=4 i=2 j=0 
// sum=6 i=2 j=1 
// sum=9 i=3 j=0 
// sum=12 i=3 j=1
// sum=16 i=4 j=0
// sum=20 i=4 j=1
// 25
```

Comment: Hi R Nair,

Thank you for the reply. Your visualization is good, I will have to look through it to gain a better understanding of why ' i ' seems to have the same value twice, and why ' j ',  "resets" back to zero and then 1 again. 

As I've stated in my reply to Barmar above, I did not expect the replies so quickly :D.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I got it! Thanks you so much! I had to look at it for a while, but I finally know how it works. :D @R-Nair

Answer (score 2):

Here are all the iterations of the loops, and the value of `sum` after each.

```
i = 0 j = 0 sum = 0 + 0 + 0 = 0
i = 0 j = 1 sum = 0 + 0 + 1 = 1
i = 1 j = 0 sum = 1 + 1 + 0 = 2
i = 1 j = 1 sum = 2 + 1 + 1 = 4
i = 2 j = 0 sum = 4 + 2 + 0 = 6
i = 2 j = 1 sum = 6 + 2 + 1 = 9
i = 3 j = 0 sum = 9 + 3 + 0 = 12
i = 3 j = 1 sum = 12 + 3 + 1 = 16
i = 4 j = 0 sum = 16 + 4 + 0 = 20
i = 4 j = 1 sum = 20 + 4 + 1 = 25
```

Comment: These calculations really helped in the end when I laid out the code. Thank you so much @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

This loop is calculated like this.

(1+2+3+4) * 2 = 20
(0+1) * 5 = 5

So sum = 20 + 5 = 25

Comment: Hi Kirill Savik,

Thank you for your reply! It is much appreciated. 
I think I am starting to gather some thoughts while reading through all the replies about how it all fits together. I'm not all the way there yet, but I think I am starting to figure it out.

Thank you again! :)

Comment: I finally understand how this fits into the code! Thank you very much for the explanation! It is very much appreciated @Kirill-Savik

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will give you more visualization of on what's going on:

```js
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
console.log("loop start");
console.log("i", i);
    for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
console.log("sum", sum);
console.log("j", j);
        sum = sum + i + j;
        continue;
    }
console.log("loop end");
}
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Hi Vanowm, 

Thank you very much for the reply! The code snippet runs perfectly! 

I have to study it more closely to wrap my head around it along with the previous replies. Again, thank you all so much! This community is amazing! 

I will look though this and once I get that light-bulb moment, I will post or vote or whatever needs to be done. I'm new to stack-overflow, so I will figure this out too.

Thank you very much again!

Comment: Thank you @vanowm for the code snippet. You guys really helped me to get it to "click" after I studied your examples and playing around with the code. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The left side would be the values of `i` and `j`:

```
0 // i
0 1 // j  // sum = 0 | sum = 1 + (0) <-- () is previous value of sum
        
1
0 1       // sum = 1 + (1) | sum = 2 + (2)
     
2
0 1       // sum = 2 + (4) | sum = 3 + (6)

3
0 1       // sum = 3 + (9) | sum = 4 + (12)

4
0 1       // sum = 4 + (16)| sum = 5 + (20)
```

Comment: Hi Hozeis,

If I understand correctly, the for-loop for ( j ) runs twice every time, but it resets its own value from 1 back to zero, at the start of each iteration of the for-loop for ( i )?
If that makes sense?

Comment: Exactly @AstonJay

Comment: Wow, ok cool! So I got that, I am going to spend a little more time with the answers here, but I think that I almost got it! :D Thank you! @Hozeis

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured it out and I understand it now :D @Hozeis